# Java: How communicate with machines?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, telnet

i'm trying to communicate with my device through java.
I can communicate with it using telnet, i know that because i use PuTTY, so my configuration is:

ip: 192.168.1.4       port: 2001          communication type: telnet

This works, my device and network is working fine.

So i though that i could do the same through java, then i create this class:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 *
 * @author Valter
 */

public class Middleware {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.4", 2001);

            // create a channel between to receive data
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // create a channel between to send data
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("}Rv!");
//            dataOutputStream.flush();

            String answer= dataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Answer:"+answer);

            dataInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEÇÃO UNKNOW HOST EXCEPTION");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEÇÃO IOEXCEPTION");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to execute this, nothing happens, no exceptions, no nothing.
I looks like a 'while' without end.

What should i do here?
I should use a client telnet to java here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to excute shell script on difference machine using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598836/how-to-excute-shell-script-on-difference-machine-using-java) and [Need to execute a shell script from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601436/need-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-java) and [Java Running Remote Bashscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577513/java-running-remote-bashscript)

Comment: Maybe what you sent is not enough, try using wireshark to check what putty sends to the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what sort of device you're talking to, but if you normally type commands to it using `telnet`, you're presumably sending newlines to it, and perhaps those newlines are needed as command terminators. So perhaps

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("}Rv!\n");
```

or

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("}Rv!\r\n");
```

(along with uncommenting that call to `flush()`) would work better.

Comment: i tried what you suggest but doesn't work, i already uncomment that flush() call.

Comment: You should either step through it with a debugger, or just insert some `System.out.println` calls to find out where it's hanging: at the `new Socket()`, at the `writeUTF()`, or at the `readUTF()`. Each would indicate a different problem.

Comment: your comment was awesome, i did some changes here and it works, but your comment was very important to me, thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

What do you really want to send to the device? DataOutputStream#writeUTF uses a Java specific string encoding and I doubt that this is what the device really expects.

Except for that, if the device is really implementing the telnet protocol properly (and not just something which can be accessed with a telnet client), you have to either use a Java telnet library to support control sequences or implement this yourself. You can't just read and write to the socket as in your example code.

Comment: i see, is what i was thinking either @jarnbjo